# Angular Detect change on html input element or trigger it automatically

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to get the value of an input element once it changes. The value is not typed by the user. I got it from a source and bind it with `[(ngModel)]` or just `[value]`. I have tried everything. But I still got nothing. I even search on how to trigger an event manually. if some of you can help me, I would be grateful

My code: I have tried various things. But this is the one that seems to work. But this instructions in the subscribe method was executed twice

```
this.maxGroup$ = this.reponseService.getMaxGroupe();

this.maxGroup$.subscribe((rep: MaxGroup) => {
    if (rep) {
        this.maxGroupe = rep;
        this.max = rep.valeur;
        this.questions.forEach(q => {
            let r = new Reponse();
            r.QuestionId = q.Id.toString();
            r.Question = q;
            r.Groupe = rep.valeur;
            this.reponses.push(r);
        });
    }
    this.max++;
    this.maxGroupe.valeur = this.max;
    let ref = this.reponseService.createMax(this.maxGroupe);
    this.reponseService.deleteMax(this.idMax);
});
```

In my service:

```
return this.db.list('/maxGroup').snapshotChanges().map(snapshots => {
  return snapshots.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...(c.payload.val()) as {} }));
});
```

In my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let m of maxGroup$ | async">
<input #KeyMax type="text" id="keyMax" [(ngModel)]="m.key" [value]="m.key" (change)="keyChange()"/>
```

Comment: Add a (change )='OnInputChanged()' function call in HTML.

Comment: Could you at least share what you have tried so far?

Comment: ...And or me it is not clear: if the the change doesn't come from a user input, where does it come from? Can't you monitor it before?

Comment: @John Peters, so I have to implement OnInputChange()? If yes, the problem is (change) is not triggered. But when I use an event like keyup.enter and then I press enter it works. But I want it to triggered aotomatically.

Comment: I was wrong, look up Angular Input Changed

Comment: @C. Champagne, the value comes from fla firebase object. My problem is when calling the service and subscribing to the observable, I have an infinite loop (may be there is something I don't understand about observables). So I tried not to subscribe to the observable by doing something like: this.firebaseObject$ = this.myService.getObject(); and my template is like: <div *ngFor="let o of firebaseObject$ | async"><input [value]="o.key" (change)="keyChange()"/></div>

Comment: @R2D2 I hadn't seen your comment when I posted my answer and I don't know  you had problem with an Observable. Could you please post your code (also how you get your observable and what kind of data you expect)  in your question? Otherwise it is impossible to answer and your question will be closed.

Comment: @C.Champagne I have edited my question.

Comment: @R2D2 Thanks for the edit. This is much better.  The `async` pipe also subscribes to the component, this is why it is called twice. Using `[(ngModel)]="m.key"` and `[value]="m.key"` is redundant. What I don't understand is why you are using an `input` while you say that the user doesn't type the value...or is it just to say that you want to detect when you receive the data that the user can modify later.

Comment: @R2D2 Another question: what are you supposed to iterate? When I look at the component code, you seem to get a single value.

Comment: I have an object with only one node: valeur. In subscribe method, I want to get valeur, increment it, create a new node and delete the previous one using the key. Because of the loop issue, I had to look for other solutions. So I put it in an input and I want to detect once it get there. For [(ngModel)] and [value], the problem is not there. I tried one at a time and I still got the problem.